# discount factor on rival and non-rival goods

Tags: economic-growth, optimal-control

I am asking to myself if we must use a different discount rate on rival and non rival goods. In standard Solow-Swann model, we use generally the discount factor $\rho$.

More formally, let's give the workhorse model used in environmental economics.

$$max \int_{0}^{\infty} u(c(t),s(t)) e^{-\rho t}$$

where $c(t)$ is consumption (rival good) and $s(t)$ is the environmental quality (or amenities) which is a non rival good by definition.

Let's say that $u(c(t),s(t))$ is an additive utility function which could be defined as

$$u(c,s)=\frac{c^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma}+\frac{s^{1-\phi}}{1-\phi}$$

where $\phi$ and $\sigma$ are elasticities. Also, to be complete, the constraint would be as

$$\dot{s}\left(t\right)=-c(t)$$

The question that I ask to myself is why an agent (or social planner) uses the same discount rate for a rival (consumption) and non rival (environmental quality.) ? For example, I have completely different preferences for consumption and environment for future. So, how can I use the same discount $\rho$ ?

There is an interesting paper of [Endres et al. (2014)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x0sqfpyjo6schln/Endres%20et%20al.%20-%202014%20-%20Intergenerational%20equity%20with%20individual%20impatience%20in%20a%20model%20of%20optimal%20and%20sustainable%20growth.pdf?dl=0) where authors use individual and social discount rates which are different. 
In appendix B. (at page 631 of the paper), they define $A$ and $B$ where they say $A\neq B$ because they say each person treats differently rival and non rival goods.

So, is there a big caveat of growth models which contain rival and non rival goods in utility function ?

Thanks in advance for your hints.